# Remove all acronyms from PHP string

Tags: php, string

I have a line of text that has acronyms inside is kind of like this...

```
$draft="The war between the CIA and NSA started in K2 when the FBI hired M";
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to create a new string with all acronyms removed.

I need this output...

```
$newdraft="The war between the and started in when the hired";
```

The only php functions I can find only remove words that you statically declare like this!

```
$newdraft= str_replace("CIA", " ", $draft);
```

Anyone have any ideas, or an already created function?

Comment: there is no already created functions for such tasks, be sure.

Comment: You have to define or get a list of acronyms beforehand.

Comment: How do you define an acryonym? Is it from one of those specific keywords, or do you want to find any acronym in a string (could be tricky!) It sounds like a job for `preg_replace()`, but your question is too ambiguous to be certain.

Comment: Yes I am looking for ANY acronym, and it is getting tricky. I define acronym as any two letter or more word where either 1: All letters are CAPS, or 2: First and last letter are CAPS. I'll take a look more into preg_replace(). I wish awk/sed could be in the web enviorment! I love my awk/sed.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, let's try to write something (albeit I can't understand what for it can be useful).

```
<?php

function remove_acronyms($str)
{
    $str_arr = explode(' ', $str);
    if (empty($str_arr)) return false;

    foreach ($str_arr as $index => $val)
    {
        if ($val==strtoupper($val)) unset($str_arr[$index]);
    }
    return implode(' ', $str_arr);
}

$draft = "The war between the CIA and NSA started in K2 when the FBI hired M";

print remove_acronyms($draft);
```

http://codepad.org/cIZSwwhV

Comment: Its useful because in the Air Force we write preformance reports using bullet statements in the following format. "Engineered NAOC comm sol; provided C2 to mobile CP--key to perfect POTUS/SECDEF msn...sq CC coined". The web application I an working on is being designed to strip all non-words such as acronyms from the above bullet statement and preform a thesaurus API lookup for all remaining "real words". That way with the click of a button you get a table of different "better sounding" words as recommended replacements.

Comment: Wow! That works perfect, and is very sexy indeed. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

*Definition of an acronym: any word that is fully capitalized, and at least 2 chars long.*

```
<?php
  $draft="The war between the CIA and NSA started in K2 when the FBI hired M";

  $words = explode(' ', $draft);
  foreach($words as $i => $word)
  {
    if (!strcmp($word, strtoupper($word)) && strlen($word) >= 2)
    {
      unset($words[$i]);
    }
  }

  $clean = implode(' ', $words);

  echo $clean;
?>
```

Comment: Of course, see the definition. I wouldn't want to remove "A" in the sentence "A little unicorn".

Comment: agree with you (about definition), but OP wants it to be deleted :)

Comment: Hum, I'm screwed then, so are you ^^

Comment: It looks like the single letter removal M is a rarity that doesn't need to be worked on. I found a workaround to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define an acronym. You'd have to cut some corners, but stating something like 'any single word that is smaller then 5 characters and in all capitals' should be correct for this sample, and you'd be able to write a regular expression for that.

Other then that, you could make a huge list of known acronyms and just replace those.

Comment: OZ_'s function was perfect for this. For another area I am going to have to do something like your recommendation. It's more for converting abbreviations into full words though. Like translating Pilot'd into Piloted and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Regex to remove multiple caps and/or numbers appearing together:

```
$draft="The war between the CIA and NSA started in K2 when the FBI hired M";
$newdraft = preg_replace('/[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]+/', '', $draft);
echo $newdraft;
```